# TaskExecutor inside a TimerTask Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a runnable inside a TimerTask, in a Spring Boot Application. The TimerTask is running every 5 seconds, which grabs constantly updating data and stores it into results. Inside the TimerTask, I need to process this data, but it takes longer than 5 seconds (usually about a minute). I would like to separate this longer task by putting it into another thread.

The general gist is as follows:

Spring boot component:

```
@Component
public class dbUpdateScheduler {
  Timer timer = new Timer(true);
  long periodInMs = 10000;
  UpdateDB mytask  = new  UpdateDB(dBaccessor);
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask , periodInMs, periodInMs);
}
```

TimerTask:

```
public class UpdateDB extends TimerTask {
 private final DBaccessor dBaccessor;

 @Autowired
 private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

 UpdateDB(DBaccessor dBaccessor) {
   this.dBAccessor = dBaccessor;
 } 

@Override
public void run() {
  Iterable <Document> results = this.dBAccessor.getstuff();
  ExtraTask extratask = new ExtraTask(results);
  taskExecutor.execute(extratask); //failing here
  }
}
```

ExtraTask.java:

```
@Configurable
public class ExtraTask implements Runnable {

  @Autowired
  private Iterable <Document> results;

  ExtraTask(Iterable <Document> results) {
   this.results = results;
  } 

  @Override
    public void run() {
    //proccess stuff
    }
}
```

Not sure how to proceed, I'm getting a nullPointerException at the execute line of taskExecutor. Would a possible solution involve autowiring results and injecting into ExtraTask?

Comment: Is `UpdateDB` a `Spring`-managed bean?

Comment: No. I've edited the code to clarify. Do I even need to use taskExecutor in this case?

Comment: I'd maybe use `@Scheduled` on a method instead: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ - and you cannot(*) do `new  UpdateDB` yourself if you want `@Autowired` fields filled. Inject an UpdateDB instance into dbUpdateScheduler

Comment: How would I be able to insert a constantly updating "results" variable into ExtraTask then?